# Kotlin app crashes when get request is started

Tags: android, kotlin

I have very basic knowledge, but basically I have a button that has a listener and when that button is pressed it should send a GET request to a specific URL but everytime I press the button it just crashes my app, logcat doesn't mention the issue and just shows that the app closed.

```
I/System: core_booster, getBoosterConfig = false
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 18019 SIG: 9
```

I have tried to used multiple libraries but they all seem to have the same result where it just crashes, I gave it internet permissions so it should be good on that part, the library im currently using on this version is khttp

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import khttp.get

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
            botao_off_1.setOnClickListener {
                val ipAddress = get(url = "http://192.168.1.1/27/off").jsonObject.getString("origin")
            }
    }
}
```

It very supposed to be very basic on the backend and only have a few buttons.

I expected it to just be able to complete the request, the IP and all the other information should be right, but it just crashes.

EDIT:Only some things I took the code DHAVAL ASODARIYA posted and adapted it, it was still crashing but I manage to track the issue down to a ConnectException so I just try and catch it everytime I make a request and now it works like butter.

*sorry for messy code*

this is just the part that actually does anything

```
    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Any?) {
        try {
            val url = params[0]
            val ipAddress = get(url as String)
        }
        catch (e: ConnectException) {}
    }
}


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
            this.botao_off_1.setOnClickListener {
                EnviarGet().execute("http://192.168.1.1/27/off")
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please set a debug point (or, show in a toast) after the `setOnClickListener()` and check what value `ipAddress` receives?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have seen your code. It seems you are making network call on main thread, which cause `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

So instead doing call on main thread use async task to make network calls.

```
class  GetMyIP : AsyncTask<Any, Any, Any>()
{

  override fun onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute()
  }

  override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Any?) {
    var url = params[0]
    // Make your network call here and return result
    TODO("not implemented") 
  }

  override fun onPostExecute(result: Any?) {
    super.onPostExecute(result)
    // The data you have return from doInBackground will be received here.
    // So now you can parse the result.
  }
}
```

Call it from button click as,

```
GetMyIP().execute("{URL HERE}")
```

Comment: It now is able to perform the GET request successfully but crashes after it sends it, its not really expecting any data from the request since im using it to control a microcontroller.